# I want to stop my Web App by setting Time arguments but it’s not working correctly

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

*Problem description:*

In my application the quiz stops when the date is not yet but the time is due but on a different date.

*Example:*

If I set date to `August/20/2022` and `endTime` to `11:00pm`, then the quiz stops on `19th August` when the time is `11:00pm`.

*My code:*

```
if (!(endTime.isBefore(now) && !(endDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now())))) {
    out.print("more time");
} else {
    stopdao.stopquiz();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use classes `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime` for server-side programming because they are **not** meant to represent a particular moment in time. They have a meaning only in the context of a particular `Local`.

For the same moment in time, `LocalDateTime` may vary in the range up `26-27` hours in different time zones.

Instead, you can use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), which represents a point in time in [*UTC*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Secondly, you've messed around with your condition.

Let's assume that `endTime` is of type `Instant`. Then all that you need is the following:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();

if (now.isBefore(endTime)) {
    out.print("more time");
} else {
    stopdao.stopquiz();
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you can get me an example I look confused

Comment: @Champ What makes you feel confused? You can manipulate with `Instant` in pretty much the same way as with `LocalDateTime`, see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Also, to get introductory information about `Instant` and other classes from `java.time` package, have a look at [this tutorial created by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all - Consider thinking about more concious use of boolean logic. This code doesn't look understandable due to negation which can be replaced with equivalent **OR** expression. If your code compiles then I presume, a dollar mark is just a mistake in typing here and is normally a closing brace ")" which is missing.

Remember that Java estimates only the necessary part of conditions. Once the evaluation can't change it's value it is fixed and nothing else is being checked. (first meet **false** in **&&** expression or first **true** in **or** expression) So if you check on the first place an hour in an **AND** expression the date will be checked ONLY in case the hour did not set the evaluation result.

Also if you use LocalDate/Time, why using negation in your logic instead simply use **(time/date).isAfter()**?

I'm not posting you the code - try fixing it yourself taking under consideration above mentioned things :)